# How to use Eureka client in RestTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have the following code:

```
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
    return restTemplate;
}


ResponseEntity<Response> response = restTemplate.exchange("http://127.0.0.1:8080/users", HttpMethod.POST, request, Response.class);


I get:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: 127.0.0.1:
```

How I can use Eureka in order to get a Eureka client and make a call using the name of the remote microservice registered into Eureka.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Solution

The general usage of `RestTemplate`  coinside with `Eureka`code snippet is following

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@RestController
public class EurekaRestTemplateExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaRestTemplateExampleApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String callOtherService() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange("http://eureka-client-service/api/endpoint", HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);
        return "Response from other service: " + response.getBody();
    }
}
```

By the way , before configure `RestTempalte`  you d better  make sure that both  `Eureka` client and server side  has been configure correctly

##### Recommendation

Specified Ip or service name in  microService with restTemplate is not recommended . because of it is too coupling  , I will show your  a  http client request componment `Fegin`

###### 1.Define a Fegin interface

The interface reference is based on Server Provider side , just type method
maintain consistency with provider side

```java
@FeignClient("eureka-client-service")
public interface MyFeignClient {

    @GetMapping("/api/endpoint")
    String getEndpointData();
}
```

###### 2.Make a Request

The rest of all is same as `RestTemplate` ,  but the usage is more compact and  convenient

```java
@RestController
public class MyController {

    private final MyFeignClient feignClient;

    @Autowired
    public MyController(MyFeignClient feignClient) {
        this.feignClient = feignClient;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String callOtherService() {
        return "Response from other service: " + feignClient.getEndpointData();
    }
}
```

##### Appendix

If you build project in maven , you can add following dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        <version>${yourFegin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I found out that I need a reactive client. Any idea how to solve this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76698733/java-lang-illegalstateexception-block-blockfirst-blocklast-are-blocking