# java.lang.NullPointerException: The Mono returned by the supplier is null

Tags: spring-webflux, webclient, spring-webclient

I have this WebClient code which I want to use in Spring Cloud Gateway:

```
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder() {
        return WebClient.builder();
    }

}  


  @Autowired
  public WebClient webClient;

  public Mono<Response> getResponse(......) {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader);

    MultiValueMap<String, String> requestBody = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    requestBody.add(.....);

    Mono<Response> responseMono = webClient.method(HttpMethod.POST)
            .uri("some usrl")
            .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.addAll(headers))
            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(requestBody))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Response.class);

    Mono<Response> customObjMono = responseMono.map(customObject -> {
      Response customObj = new Response();
      customObj.setAccessToken(customObject.getAccessToken());
      return customObj;
    });

    return customObjMono;
  }


Mono<Response> tokden = client.getResponse(........);
      AtomicReference<Response> plainJavaObject = new AtomicReference<>();
      tokden.subscribe(transformedToken -> {
        plainJavaObject.set(transformedToken);
      });
      Response token = plainJavaObject.get();
```

Unfortunately response is not received. I get error

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! null
2023-07-22 19:12:05.533 ERROR 2668 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [b59e780c-3]  500 Server Error for HTTP POST "/greeting"

java.lang.NullPointerException: The Mono returned by the supplier is null
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:233) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/greeting" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
```

Full code example:

https://github.com/rcbandit111/gateway_reactive_feign_poc

Comment: done , and  why change  http util  reactive-fegin  to   webclient ?

Comment: it just a util , and webclient  is  programing model ,it is   appropriate  for  complex project and customize  required. For simple project required ,reactive-fegin is declarative  programing  model  it is more compact and  convenient that webclient.

Comment: I want to try also the test it.

Comment: I can't find why `BasicTokenResponseDto token` is null. I changed the return object of the DTO but again it's bull. Any idea why?

Comment: @Peng Looks like we need to use `(exchange, chain) -> { .....}` in order to get properly the response: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-custom-gateway-filters#3-chaining-requests-to-other-services

Comment: okay  i will research this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. gateway exchange filter chain could not return null ,[fix]
2. make sure the api reference provide side coinside with consumer side
3. checkout your request args in your postman ,  endpoint `greeting` has been routing to the endpoing service ,no longer via webclient which is define in the gateway exchange filter   , so  your recent modification is out of expected .

for previous postman config , have a look in this  [link](https://planetary-robot-926308.postman.co/workspace/github%7Ee685951b-81d1-40d8-a6fc-568586335e0f/collection/16761636-c12c816c-11f5-4b27-8dd2-c35dbac51333?action=share&creator=16761636)

Comment: I saw the branch `feature/pengpengon` but it's not using Spring WebClient?

Comment: i commit that  ain  new branach which i guess  that is your branch  ```feature-superdev```

Comment: yes. Sorry I don't get you in which branch is your latest code?

Comment: now is ok,  have a look at  branch ```master```

Comment: hm... Into Java class ClientService I don't see method getJwt() called inside method `filter`.

Comment: yes , because ``` /greeing```` is routing to endpoint directly  via spring gateway   , it is unnecessary that  request in project again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254657/discussion-between-peng-and-peter-penzov).