# springcloud-eureka,No instances available for user-service,but i find user-service at dashboard

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWtvB.png)

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instances available for user-service
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:119) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:99) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerInterceptor.intercept(LoadBalancerInterceptor.java:56) ~[spring-cloud-commons-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:77) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:782) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:717) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:367) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at com.hwadee.manager.controller.QuestionController.getInfo(QuestionController.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:529) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1790) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_202]
```

This is my practice project architecture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WW3kw.png)

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/question")
public class QuestionController {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private static final String URL_PREFIX = "http://user-service";

    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public AjaxResult getInfo() {
//        String url = "http://localhost:8080/user/get/" + id;
        String url = URL_PREFIX + "/user/get/1";
        System.out.println(url);

        ResponseEntity<AjaxResult> forEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, AjaxResult.class);
        AjaxResult body = forEntity.getBody();

        System.out.println(body);
        return AjaxResult.success("successful", body);
    }
}
```

The address of the request I initiated is `http://localhost:8081:/question/list`

If I initiate the above request, I will report an error

`user-service` is already configured in another service

```java
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfig {
    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableFeignClients
public class QuestionApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(QuestionApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

it's user-service starter

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@MapperScan("com.hwadee.manager.mapper")
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class UserApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

#### After the service started, I saw it on the eureka dashboard, but when I called it, I found that it would make an error. I don't know where my problem occurred. If you need code from another place, please let me know. If you can't find the problem at the moment, you can also give me some suggestions. Thank you very much!

Comment: What version of spring cloud are you using as ribbon is no longer supported

Comment: demonstrate  error stack  , and  it is uncessary that  specified the url prefix with  host name in your code ,  if you would like to study  spring cloud  , you d better  read the [spring cloud doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/docs/3.1.8/reference/html/) . it is inconvenient senario that use the restTemplate directly , we often use annotation-driven  .   or else  you can refer to folloing link [How to use Eureka client in RestTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76698694/how-to-use-eureka-client-in-resttemplate/76698907#76698907)